# Android Intent-Filter for http address

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am trying to intercept a couple different links with my app, and I am having trouble with the intent-filter data parameters to do it.

Here are the 2 types of links that I want to intercept

1. http://www.domain.com/#id=abcdef123346
2. http://www.domain.com/social/landing/abcdef123456

I have already decided to have a separate activity to intercept both links and use java regex to start the correct activity. However I can't seem to capture just these two formats without capturing something like http://www.domain.com/abc123

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.domain.com"
                android:pathPattern="/#id.*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is what I am currently trying to intercept type 1 and for some reason it isn't working.

This intent-filter correctly intercepts type 2

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="domain.com" />
            <data android:host="www.domain.com" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/share/web" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/social/landing" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hey @leo i want to achieve same thing i just want to open my app when the user launch mobile site from browser i did same thing here but it doesn't work any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the string that pathPattern is matching is "/", and "#id..." is omitted because it is part of the fragment. If you used http://www.domain.com/id/abcdef123456 instead, pathPattern could match "/id/.*" because it is part of the path.

Comment: This is definitely a possibility, but involves changing server behavior, was hoping wouldn't have to do that. Any other possibilities?

Comment: I don't see any option for a pathFragment. Could you just catch everything that goes to "/" and get the ID out later?

Comment: Unfortunately if I intercept all links that have a slash in them, I will stop my short urls from resolving, and not be able to figure out what the actual target was.

Comment: I went with this solution, since I haven't been able to figure out any other way. Thanks.

Comment: This is the behaviour you have to expect. The fragment (everything after the `#`) doesn't identify the resource you want to retrieve: it's extra data to be interpreted by the client/browser. The resource to retrieve has to be uniquely identified by the rest of the URL.