# how to launch own application when user open browoser

Tags: android, browser, android-manifest

I want to start up own android application when user click the browser,such as user access wap.sohu.com in  UC Web,Chrome etc. some tips regarding add data element in Mainifest.xml. but it is not I needed. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not well-formed. It is hard to understand your problem. However, it seems that you need `intent-filter` for HTTP URL scheme. Here is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179776/android-intent-filter-for-http-address and tutorial: http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/launching-an-android-application-from-a-url/ and, finally, official documentation of what can and what can't be done w/ intent filters: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

sorry,maybe i cannot write clearly. I need the tecknology to display a window when user accessing browser. intent-filter for http url may cause a prompt for user choosing. it's not my need.